# imagick function to read pdf files

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$file_path = $this->filePath.'d/'.$this->compId.'/'.$data->project_id.'/'.$result[0]->file_name;

$im = new Imagick();    
$im->pingImage($file_path);
```

I am not able to get the pdf file response using the above code.

> Error:-**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with
> message 'Failed to read the file' in
> /srv/www/api.proofhub.com/public_html/application/core/v2/proof.php:114
>
> Stack trace:
> #0 /srv/www/api.proofhub.com/public_html/application/core/v2/proof.php(114):
> Imagick->pingimage('/srv/www/api.pr...')

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the file path before continuing:

```
$file_path = $this->filePath.'d/'.$this->compId.'/'.$data->project_id.'/'.$result[0]->file_name;
if (! file_exists($file_path)) {
  die('the file path '.$file_path.' does not appear to exist');
}
```

Comment: it's not working , can you please suggest any other solution for it!

Comment: does it die and tell you the file_path does not exist?